# Using Direct2D drawing with real-time data from a timer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, direct2d

I'm using Direct2D with MFC and would like to know how to use real-time data to update a render target. For instance, I have the following AFX_WM_DRAW2D handler:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CTestView::OnDraw2d(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CString text;
    CHwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;
    ASSERT_VALID(pRenderTarget);

    // Clear window background
    pRenderTarget->Clear(ColorF(ColorF::Beige));

    // Draw text
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    text.Format(_T("%i"), value);
    pRenderTarget->DrawText(text, rect, m_pBlueBrush, m_pTextFormat);
    return TRUE;
}
```

The variable 'value' is updated globally by a timer:

```
void CTestView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    CRect rect;
    this->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    this->InvalidateRect(&rect);
    if (value == NULL)
        value = 0;
    value++;
    CView::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to make the interface be redrawn with the updated variable displayed via Direct2D. What is the best way to do this? I've read that Direct2D is much faster than GDI so I figured I would give it a shot for dealing with constantly updated variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Direct2D is hardly ever faster than GDI, unless you already have a Direct3D application. Regardless of that, the logic to redraw the UI is identical for GDI and Direct2D: Whenever your code logic deduces the need to refresh the UI, call `InvalidateRect`, and wait for the `WM_PAINT`-handler to be invoked.

Comment: please show code where did you call OnDraw2d. I have been worked on a pure win32 app which have the same requirement. just call drawing function in response of WM_PAINT message.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, [drawing operations can only be issued between a `BeginDraw()` and `EndDraw()` call.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You have to call EnableD2DSupport(); That’s all. No need to create a render target, resize it, recreating it when nesessary, calling BeginDraw, EndDraw, etc. All is done in the MFC framework if D2D support is enabled for a window.